# Request from different Country IP

Tags: python, proxy, ip

I would like to view the movie content from a different country on the Playstation store. However, the playstation store blocks the IP based on location of the request, so a movie in Canada cannot be viewed from the US:

https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-ca/movies/the-house/cid=UV0130-NPVA92773_CN-0000000000236063

Is there a way to do something like the following:

```
url = 'https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-ca/movies/the-house/cid=UV0130-NPVA92773_CN-0000000000236063'
r = requests.get(url, proxy_from = COUNTRY['CA']) # In pseudocode
```

Basically, so that you can specify a country and then send a request from an IP that would be recognized as coming from that country. How would this be done?

Comment: It's worth noting that what you're trying to do almost certainly violates Sony's ToS, which, depending on where you live, might give them legitimate grounds for canceling your subscripting without a refund, or might even be illegal. If you know that and want to do it anyway, that's up to you, of course, but make sure you're aware of what you're doing.

Comment: @abarnert understood. This is more to verify that a price has dropped in a certain country for a certain title (a title that we own or manage). It's for being able to audit the price from the end user's perspective.

Comment: Do you have a proxy server or VPN server or something like that?

Comment: This website seems to contain lots of JS code. I don't think simply using `requests` is enough for getting the content.

Comment: @skyline75489 that's correct. There is an 'api endpoint' that is loaded within the page, and that's what is being requested to parse the information. For example: https://store.playstation.com/chihiro-api/pc-storetree/US/en/999/STORE-MSF77008-BASE?size=30&geoCountry=US

Comment: Then perhaps you may want to update you question with this endpoint url?

Comment: For the first URL that's blocked from countries other than Canada, the endpoint inside is actually gives a response. So...problem solved?  https://store.playstation.com/chihiro-api/viewfinder/CA/en/999/UV0130-NPVA92773_CN-0000000000236063?size=30&gkb=1&geoCountry=CN

Comment: @skyline75489 -- yea, I removed that part as it wasn't that relevant to the question. I'm more interested in just being able to **load** the Canada page.

Comment: https://www.tunnelbear.com/
try this vpn service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are basically asking how to make a url request in python using a proxy?

If yes, you can do it like follows:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import random

CAproxies = [{"http":"199.201.122.175:3128", "https":"199.201.122.175:3128"},{"http":"192.99.3.129:3128", "https":"192.99.3.129:3128"},{"http":"192.99.246.101:8118", "https":"192.99.246.101:8118"},{"http":"205.205.129.130:443", "https":"205.205.129.130:443"} ]


proxies = urllib2.ProxyHandler(random.choice(CAproxies))

url = 'https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-ca/movies/the-house/cid=UV0130-NPVA92773_CN-0000000000236063'

request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
request.add_header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxies)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
r = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=15)
html = r.read()
```

The headers are good if you want the service to think you are using a browser, they usually have defences against bots. You need to replace the proxy address with your own proxy, this is just an invented proxy for illustration purposes.

A list of Proxies can be found here for example:
http://www.proxy-listen.de/Proxy/Proxyliste.html 
In case the proxy given above doesn't work.
In case one of the proxies work better for your particular location (lets say the 2nd one works best for you, it might be a good idea to change the random choice of a proxy to only the second one. i.e.

```
random.choice(CAproxies) -> CAproxies[1]
```

CAproxies[3] works the best for me.
The first 250 characters from the html:

```
>>> html[0:250]
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n\n<html class="ctry mobvportA rgba">\n  <head>\n    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />\n    <meta charset="utf-8"/>\n\n    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ajax.googleapis.com">\n    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ssl.'
```

Comment: Thanks, could you show a real-example of that with a Canadian proxy, to show that the url returns a real response? After that, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: You can find proxies here for example: http://www.proxy4free.com/list/webproxy1.html
I can add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is just diagnose and try to figure out if that is possible at all.

First thing you can do is using a `VPN` or any `Proxy` simulate your location as coming from Canada. If that works, and you are able to load the required page, then most probably the location is determined from the request IP.

And actually from the viewpoint of the service, in your case the **Playstation store**, there is no other reliable piece of information to retrieve client's geo-location from.

So if this is the situation, the only reasonable solution for your problem would be to change your IP address somehow. But anyway, if you do that on your application side, there will be too many layers, e.g. routers, that will anyway expose your real location, as the final `IP packet` that reaches the service, will contain the real `real IP`.

Thus, it is nothing to do with your application or request client, you should rather think about what to put in front of it.

So if your question is:

> How to achieve my goal on the application side?

...then the answer is: *most probably no way* :/

But if you ask:

> How can I achieve my goal?

...then there are options:

- Use `proxy` or `VPN`. You will certainly find a VPN service, that will provide access credentials (e.g. `OpenVPN config`) per location, so you can load them programatically. That can be implemented on your application side.
- And the reckless...have machines in each location you want to request from :)

Comment: @David542 if you end up using `OpenVPN`, I can help you out with `python` code for controlling it, as there are some tricky pieces.